# how to view Powershell output in textbox ASP.Net

Tags: c#, powershell

First of all, I want to really thank everyone in the forum. It has helped a lot in researching many solutions.

OK.. so here I have this code below that I found online and it does what is intended at the moment. However, when running the project to then click the button to execute, it will then provide the result but after is done running the script. I've been looking around to see if there's a way in which I can make or display the output of the PS script dynamically (as being executed) to the a text box or a dummy simulated terminal within the aspx.

```
protected void ExecuteCode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Clean the Result TextBox
            ResultBox.Text = string.Empty;

            // Initialize PowerShell engine
            var shell = PowerShell.Create();

            // Add the script to the PowerShell object
            string pscontent = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\..\..\..\..\..\Scripts\automation_test.ps1");
            shell.Commands.AddScript(pscontent);
            shell.Commands.AddParameter("O365Decom", Input.Text);

            // Execute the script
            var results = shell.Invoke();

            // display results, with BaseObject converted to string
            // Note : use |out-string for console-like output
            if (results.Count > 0)
            {
                // We use a string builder ton create our result text
                var builder = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (var psObject in results)
                {
                    // Convert the Base Object to a string and append it to the string builder.
                    // Add \r\n for line breaks
                    builder.Append(psObject.BaseObject.ToString() + "\r\n");
                }

                // Encode the string in HTML (prevent security issue with 'dangerous' caracters like < >
                ResultBox.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(builder.ToString());
            }

            //shell.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: You need to execute the PS command asynchronously (call `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke`) and use the `DataAdded` event to be notified whenever the command produced output. There is a nice blog post about this [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/).

Comment: @Klaus Gütter Thanks for the suggestion. Funny... I already have that site bookmarked from previous research. Question, would this be able to get integrated with web app to display script progress?
Apologies for the questions. I'm new to coding learning on my own.

Comment: @KlausGütter After few days of reading that blog multiple times, I finally figured it out and got it to work in C# Console app. Really appreciate for taking your time in reading my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Klaus and spending multiple attempts in reading the blog, I finally got it to work but in C# Console app. Below is the code I ended up using at this very moment

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (PowerShell psInstance = PowerShell.Create())
        {

            Console.Clear();

            string pscontent = File.ReadAllText(@".\Scripts\" + args[0]);
            psInstance.AddScript(pscontent)
            .AddParameter("Servicenumber", args[1])
            .AddParameter("APIVersion", args[2]);

            PSDataCollection<PSObject> outputCollection = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();
            outputCollection.DataAdded += OutputCollection_DataAdded;
            psInstance.Streams.Error.DataAdded += Error_DataAdded;

            IAsyncResult results = psInstance.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, outputCollection);

            Console.WriteLine("Script status: " + psInstance.InvocationStateInfo.State, Console.ForegroundColor=ConsoleColor.Green);
            Console.ResetColor();

            foreach(PSObject outItem in outputCollection)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(outItem.BaseObject.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Error_DataAdded(object sender, DataAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("Something got jacked up:\n");
        Console.ResetColor();
    }

    private static void OutputCollection_DataAdded(object sender, DataAddedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Something added to output\n");
    }
```